# Transfer funds to stripe user card

Tags: stripe-payments

We are running a subscription site where users will charge every week for their subscription. For this, we have used stripe and users add their cards. We store users' customer ref and using that we charge customers every week. All of this works fine and we have implemented using payment intent.
Now we want an option to transfer money to the customer's card in case they have any balance to be paid. This balance could be over a number of weeks' worth of cashback etc.., so we can't really refund any transaction.
So is there any option in Stripe to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pay out money is via [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect), when you have a service provider relationship. This requires creating and verifying [connected accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts).

Stripe does not support sending money to customer credit/debit cards like you're describing.